# Update multiple columns from another dataframe based on one common column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following two dataframes:

df1:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1  bjs      cyq  2018     12
1   2  bjs      cyq  2019      6
2   3   sh       hp  2018      4
3   4  shs      hpq  2019      3
```

df2:

```
   id city district  year
0   1   bj       cy  2018
1   2   bj       cy  2019
2   4   sh       hp  2019
```

let's say some values in `city` and `district` from `df1` have errors, so I need to update `city` and `district` values' in `df1` with those of `df2` based on `id`, my expected result is like this:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       cy  2018     12
1   2   bj       cy  2019      6
2   3   sh       hp  2018      4
3   4   sh       hp  2019      3
```

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

**Update:**

Solution 1:

```
cities = df2.set_index('id')['city']
district = df2.set_index('id')['district']

df1['city'] = df1['id'].map(cities)
df1['district'] = df1['id'].map(district)
```

Solution 2:

```
df1[["city","district"]] = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["id"],how="left")[["city_y","district_y"]]

print(df1)
```

Out:

```
   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       cy  2018     12
1   2   bj       cy  2019      6
2   3  NaN      NaN  2018      4
3   4   sh       hp  2019      3
```

Note the `city` and `district` for `id` is `3` are `NaN`s, but I want keep the values from `df1`.

Comment: I only want to update the two columns based on `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  `combine_first`:

```
df2.set_index('id').combine_first(df1.set_index('id')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id city district  price    year
0   1   bj       cy   12.0  2018.0
1   2   bj       cy    6.0  2019.0
2   3   sh       hp    4.0  2018.0
3   4   sh       hp    3.0  2019.0
```

Comment: But this will also effectuate year column from df2 to df1, right?

Comment: Yes, but we can filter it down to certain columns.

Comment: You mean by dropping year column in df2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df1[["city","district"]] = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=["id"],how="left")[["city_y","district_y"]]
```

Comment: If `df2` doesn't contain all `id` from `df1`, so I want keep rows which are not `df1`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use `.map`

edit - input changed.

```
target_cols = ['city','district']

df1.loc[df1['id'].isin(df2['id']),target_cols] = np.nan

cities = df2.set_index('id')['city']
district = df2.set_index('id')['district']

df1['city'] = df1['city'].fillna(df1['id'].map(cities))
df1['district'] = df1['district'].fillna(df1['id'].map(cities))


print(df1)

   id city district  year  price
0   1   bj       bj  2018     12
1   2   bj       bj  2019      6
2   3   sh       hp  2018      4
3   4   sh       sh  2019      3
```

Comment: Same problem as @Rajith's solution. I update question, please check.

Comment: Yes. All `id` in `df2` are contained in `df1`, for `id` in `df1` which are not `df2`, I want keep their original values in `df1`.

Comment: @ahbon okay then we can use `fillna` but I think `combine_first` is much better in this instance.